# How to intercept the gnome notify

Tags: linux, gnome

I want to get notify that show in gnome, but some notify can't intercept by dbus-monitor. Is there any way get gnome notify?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEmA7.png)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/697973 this helps?\

Comment: thanks for reply, but dbus-monitor can only get message send by notify-send in ubuntu 20.04.